# Exponential smoothing method for forecasting

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting

I want to perform the method exponential smoothing with seasonality and trend. Is holt winters the method to use?

Since I want use this to forecast values in later months.

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Holt-Winters is a form of exponential smoothing that includes trend and seasonality. Read about it at https://otexts.org/fpp2/holt-winters.html